# XSSFWorkbook#write() results in empty response

Tags: jsf-2, apache-poi

I'm trying to get my JSF to export a spreadsheet for download.  I'm using Apache's POI library for the Excel document writing.  I get the following error in an alert box when the code runs:

```
emptyResponse: An empty response was received from the server.
```

The method generating the spreadsheet and exporting to the OutputStream is below (I have renamed classes, methods etc for simplicity sake).

```
private void generateSpreadsheet(Object object) throws Exception {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse)context.getExternalContext().getResponse();

    String fileName = object.getProperty() + ".xlsx";
    response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + fileName +"\"");
    OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();

    Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
    Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Sheet 1");
    Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
    Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
    cell.setCellValue("test");
    wb.write(os);

    os.flush();
    os.close();
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
}
```

Any advice much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: If it makes a difference, I'm using AJAX (<f:ajax> tag) on the form submit that calls this method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *If it makes a difference, I'm using AJAX (`<f:ajax>` tag) on the form submit that calls this method.*

It makes definitely difference. You can **not** download files by Ajax. Ajax is executed by JavaScript code. But JavaScript has no facilities to force a *Save As* dialogue or to execute the platform default application associated with the file's mime type (thankfully; that would have been a major security/intrusion problem). Further, the JSF Ajax API expects a XML response in a specified structure conform the JSF specs. When you send a complete Excel file instead, the whole Ajax response would be ignored as ununderstandable garbage by the JSF Ajax API.

You need to send a normal synchronous request. Remove the `<f:ajax>` tag from the command link/button. The current page will remain the same anyway if the download is sent as an `attachment`.

Comment: Will validators still fire as usual without the Ajax call?

Comment: Surely they will. As long as you're using JSF provided validation API.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks.  Removing the AJAX call fixed the problem.